# ChromiumWebBrowser does not exist in the namespace in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am inserting the chromium web browser (cef sharp) in WPF but it is showing error that ChromiumWebBrowser does not exist in the namespace although i have already added the namespace and already installed CefSharp.WPF from the NuGet manager. Following is the code on which it is showing error.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cefSharp="namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="Browser"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What is the target framework of your application? For the latest cefsharp you need 4.5.2 or higher (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#release-branches).

Comment: using 4.5.2 and for x64 app

Comment: maybe it is just a typo, put clr- before the namespace, xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"

Comment: i did it but didn't get any effect

Comment: Did you try to restart your VS? Did you check that your debug settings are x64?

Comment: Yeah working now. Thanks